# Perl: Format table with curl outputs

Tags: perl, formatting

I have something like the following curl code:

```
foreach my $value ('1', ..., '5') {
    my $count = 1;
    print "\nValue: $value\n\t";
    my $start = `curl -m 10 -s "http://SITE/?value=$value" -c cookie.txt`;
    my $end1 = `curl -m 10 -s "http://SITE2" -b cookie.txt`;
    if($end1 ne "") {print ". "}; else print "$count ";
    my $end2 = `curl -m 10 -s "http://SITE3" -b cookie.txt`;
    if($end2 ne "") {print ". "}; else print "$count ";
    my $end3 = `curl -m 10 -s "http://SITE4" -b cookie.txt`;
    if($end3 ne "") {print ". "}; else print "$count ";
    $count++;
}
```

So from value `1` to `5`, it visits a website and stores the cookie value in cookie.txt. Then it visits 3 different websites using the stored cookies in cookie.txt. Once it visits these sites, it prints current count (or `.` if the request timed out after 10 seconds).

An example output for this would be:

```
Value: 1
    1 1 1 2 . 2 3 3 3 4 . . . 5 5
Value: 2
    . . 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 . 4 5 5 .
```

Would it be possible to format the output to look like:

```
Value: 1
    Site2: 1 2 3 4 .
    Site3: 1 . 3 . 5
    Site4: 1 2 3 . 5
Value: 2
    Site2: . 2 3 4 5
    Site3: . 2 3 . 5
    Site4: 1 2 3 4 .
```

The issue I have is that in the loop, I would only like to run `$start` once per loop. With the way I want it formatted, it would have to be run once per site (3 times).

Comment: As it is written, `$count` will only change at the end of each loop -- corresponding with `$value` -- is that really what you want? For your desired output format, it would seem that you need a separate loop within, no? And why are you still forking to `curl` when there are so many ways to do it with cpan modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is a bit confusing, but this will give you the output you're seeking:

```
my @sites = qw( SITE2 SITE3 SITE4 );
foreach my $value ('1'..'5') {
    print "\nValue: $value\n";
    my $start = `curl -m 10 -s "http://SITE/?value=$value" -c cookie.txt`;        
    for my $site (@sites) { 
       print "\t$site ";
       for (1..5) { # assuming you want to fetch each url 5x
          my $end = `curl -m 10 -s "http://$site" -b cookie.txt`;
          print $end eq '' ? '. ' : $_.' '; 
       }
       print "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings`. 
If you did, you'd find:

```
foreach my $value ('1', ..., '5') {
    print $value,"\n";
}
```

Is a syntax error. Which is not a good start. Perhaps you want:

```
foreach my $value ( 1..5) {
    print $value,"\n";
}
```

Likewise you've to a `$count` variable that you never change, because you scope it locally within your loop (via `my`) and set it to 1 each iteration. And then increment it right at the end, just before it drifts out of scope.

Comment: I'm sure his _real_ code is different, else he'd never have seen '2' for `$value`. The `...` is a placeholder in the same way that SITE and SITE2 are.

Comment: @BenGrimm is correct. This is a simple example I put together. My actual code would be too cibfusing

Comment: I would have to question the answerability of code examples that simply don't work.